# Confusion about NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, arrays, nullreferenceexception

As far as I know `Console.WriteLine()` (or `Console.Write()`) calls object's `ToString()` method to get the string represantation of the object right ? So those two calls to `Console.WriteLine()` are the same right ?

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

Console.WriteLine(foo); // This is same as the one bellow 
Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString());
```

So lets assume the following situation. I declare an instantiate an array of Foos.

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[10]; // After this line all 10 Foos are `null`s
```

Then I call the Console.WriteLine() on any element of the array without instantiating the Foos itself. So in this case we have an array of Foos and every Foo in the array is `null` so the call to the Console.WriteLine() should cause a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown right ? But the things is if you call it like this

```
Console.WriteLine(foos[0])
```

nothing happens except for the `Environment.NewLine` being written in the console window but if you call it like this

```
Console.WriteLine(foos[0].ToString())
```

it actually throws a `NullReferenceException`. What is the difference between those two calls? I mean in first one I don't call `ToString()` explicitly but should not it be called implicitly by Console.WriteLine() anyway ? And how does the `NullReferenceException` is not thrown in the first case ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So those two calls to Console.WriteLine() are the same right ?

No. Because `Console.WriteLine` *doesn't* call `ToString` on a null reference - it just uses the empty string instead. It detects that itself.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) explicitly states this:

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the ToString method of value is called to produce its string representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard output stream.

With no call to `ToString`, there's no `NullReferenceException`.

`string.Format` behaves the same way. For example:

```
object value = null;
string text = string.Format("Value: '{0}'", value);
```

will set `text` to `Value: ''`

Answer (score 5):

[Console.WriteLine Method (Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx)

> If value is `null`, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the `ToString` method of value is called to produce its string representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard output stream.

So `Console.WriteLine(obj)` and `Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString())` are not exactly the same.

And a little bit of code:

```
public virtual void WriteLine(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        this.WriteLine();
        return;
    }
    IFormattable formattable = value as IFormattable;
    if (formattable != null)
    {
        this.WriteLine(formattable.ToString(null, this.FormatProvider));
        return;
    }
    this.WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(foos[0])
```

in the above line as it is null therefore according to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) line terminator will be written and nothing else. I assume it will be first checking if the object is null then write line terminator otherwise call the `ToString()` method on object. Whereas

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString())
```

is calling the ToString method on null which is an exception.